# Blogger: Having A Featured Image Possible?

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I'm working on a custom responsive template for Blogger. Since Blogger doesn't have a "featured image" feature like Wordpress, is there a way that I can make the first image embedded in the post appear above the post-body and post-title? is there some kind of if/conditional statement that I can use?

Or, would it be best for me to HTML the post-title inside the post itself below the first embedded image? However, if I followed that method, how do I make the image within the post link to the post itself without editing it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to grab the first image, you can use make use of the template tag - `<data:post.firstImageUrl/>`

Below Example might help you out.

```
 <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
 <img expr:src ="data:post.firstImageUrl" expr:alt="data:post.title"/>
 </b:if>
```

This will work only within the Blogger's Post Loop

Another way of using Featured images will be to use an image link in the enclosures and to edit your template to render enclosure links as featured thumbnails. My Blog post might help you with this (http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2011/09/post-thumbnails-for-blogger.html) . It hasn't been updated for over 2 years, but it might give you some guidance.